# UI router login form submission

Tags: angularjs, user-interface, router

I currently have code for a form submission login that works with ng-route, however i want to convert it to UI router. I currently have MVC java controller for rest services. However here is my main app with configure statements:

```
var reportingDashboard = angular
    .module('reportingDashboard', [ 'ngRoute', 'ui.router', 'ngMdIcons', 'chart.js'])
    .config(

            function($routeProvider, $httpProvider, $stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {

                $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

            /*  $routeProvider.when('/', {
                    templateUrl : '/home/temp.html',
                    controller : 'home',
                    controllerAs : 'controller'
                }).when('/login', {
                    templateUrl : '/home/loginCtrl/login.html',
                    controller : 'navigation',
                    controllerAs : 'controller'
                }).otherwise("/")
                */

                $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

                $stateProvider
                .state('login',{
                    url:'/login',
                    templateUrl : '/home/loginCtrl/login.html',
                    controller : 'navigation',
                    controllerAs : 'controller'

                })
                .state('home',{
                    url:'/',
                    templateUrl : '/home/temp.html',
                    controller : 'home',
                    controllerAs : 'controller'
                })
                .state('home.index', {
                    views:{
                        '': {
                            templateUrl:"/home/reportingTemp/repoHtml.html"
                        },
                        'reportingGraph':{
                            templateUrl:'/home/reportingTemp/repoGraph.html',
                            controller: 'reportingGraphCtrl'
                        }
                    }
                })
                .state('home.admin', {
                    views:{
                        '': {
                            templateUrl:"/home/adminTemp/adminHtml.html"
                        },
                        'adminGraph':{
                            templateUrl:'/home/adminTemp/adminReport.html',
                            controller:'adminCtrl'
                        }
                    }
                })





                $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';

            }).run(function(auth) {

        // Initialize auth module with the home page and login/logout path
        // respectively
                console.log("is the auth function being called?")
        auth.init('/', '/login', '/logout');

    });
```

From this I have the auth factory:

```
reportingDashboard.factory(
        'auth',

        function($rootScope, $http, $location) {

            enter = function() {
                if ($location.path() != auth.loginPath) {
                    console.log($location.path());
                    auth.path = $location.path();
                    if (!auth.authenticated) {
                        $location.path(auth.loginPath);
                    }
                }                   
            }

            var auth = {

                authenticated : false,

                loginPath : '/login',
                logoutPath : '/logout',
                homePath : '/',
                path : $location.path(),

                authenticate : function(credentials, callback) {

                    var headers = credentials && credentials.username ? {
                        authorization : "Basic "
                                + btoa(credentials.username + ":"
                                        + credentials.password)
                    } : {};

                    $http.get('user', {
                        headers : headers
                    }).success(function(data) {
                        if (data.name) {
                            auth.authenticated = true;
                        } else {
                            auth.authenticated = false;
                            console.log("The use isnt logged in")
                        }
                        callback && callback(auth.authenticated);
                        $location.path(auth.path==auth.loginPath ? auth.homePath : auth.path);
                    }).error(function() {
                        auth.authenticated = false;
                        callback && callback(false);
                    });

                },

                clear : function() {
                    $location.path(auth.loginPath);
                    auth.authenticated = false;
                    $http.post(auth.logoutPath, {}).success(function() {
                        console.log("Logout succeeded");
                    }).error(function(data) {
                        console.log("Logout failed");
                    });
                },

                init : function(homePath, loginPath, logoutPath) {

                    auth.homePath = homePath;
                    auth.loginPath = loginPath;
                    auth.logoutPath = logoutPath;

                    auth.authenticate({}, function(authenticated) {
                        if (authenticated) {
                            $location.path(auth.path);
                        }
                    })

                    // Guard route changes and switch to login page if unauthenticated
                    $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function() {
                        enter();
                    });

                }

            };

            return auth;

        });
```

From this I have the navigation controller:

```
    reportingDashboard.controller(
            'navigation',

            function($route, auth, $location) {

                var self = this;

                self.credentials = {};

                self.tab = function(route) {
                    return $route.current && route === $route.current.controller;
                };

                self.authenticated = function() {
                    return auth.authenticated;
                }

                self.login = function() {
                    auth.authenticate(self.credentials, function(authenticated) {
                        if (authenticated) {
                        console.log("Login succeeded")

                        self.error = false;
                    } else {
                        console.log("Login failed")

                        self.error = true;
                    }
                })
            };

            self.logout = auth.clear;

        });
```

Also i have the home controller as well:

```
reportingDashboard.controller('home', function($http) {
var self = this;
$http.get('/user/').success(function(data) {
    self.user = data.name;
});
```

});

the console just returns a 401 and redirects me to the home page of the application. Any advice would be great Thankyou!! I can include any more info if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion: in angular.run function bind listener to $stateChangeStart event. Each time user will go to some state, you will check that user is authenficated. If he is, continue transition, else - save transition state and params, go to login page and after user will successfully logged in, you will redirect him to requested state/page. Something like this:

```
myApp.run(function ($rootScope, principal, $state, myStateProvider, userService) {
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState, toParams) {
        if (toState.name !== 'login') {
            myStateProvider.setNextState(toState, toParams);
        }
        if (!principal.isAuthenticated()) {
            event.preventDefault();
            principal.checkAuthentication().then(function() {
                $state.go(toState, toParams);
            });
        } else if (principal.isAuthenticated() && toState.name === 'login') {
            event.preventDefault();
            myStateProvider.redirectFromLogin();
        }
    });
```

})

Comment: I'm only an intern at the moment, but this is essentially what im trying to achieve, my only question is in my current application do I replace my entire auth.js file or do i just replace the $rootScope.$on function? Sorry for all the questions this stuff is utterly fascinating but a tad bit over my head,

Comment: I just described concept. You should to define place where this concept should be used by youself.

Comment: One quick question What are you referring to when you speak of a principal?

Comment: @user3715245 it is provider where all auth data stored. In my case isAuthenticated method checks that, for example, some private variable like _identity has non-empty value. checkAuthentication, again in my case, calls server to fetch user data and after it is fetched, data is stored in _identity variable.